# What defines a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

Recently I've starting a project I'm calling 'JIL' or JIL Interfacing Language, and it's to be a programming language of sorts. Now, I doubt it will ever be super-useful or versatile, but the aim of it is to be a step up from block programming, but a step down from complex languages like java, C, or C++. JIL stands for JIL Interfacing Language because it is both interpreted and parsed in java, and all of its keywords/methods will be interpreted and then executed in java. My question is would JIL count as a 'true' programming language, or is it a 'false' or 'secondary' programming language that is nothing more than a java application.

Comment: [Read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language). Then consider that 1) Java does not "compile to CPU" and 2) Many popular languages are not even required to compile to a byte-code 3) There are both compiled and "parsed" implementations of several languages.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "true programming language". There are only "programming languages" and it sounds like your project is one.

Comment: @user2864740 So no? It is only a java application? Sorry, having trouble understanding what you are trying to say, the link defines a programing language as something that gives instructions to a machine, but would giving instructions to a intepreter that executes java code count as programminglanguage because it is instead giving instructions to java, which in turn gives instructions to the machine.

Comment: @meguy26 If I write something like `System.out.println("Hello world!")`, or the equivalent in your language, then it prints "Hello world!", doesn't it? That is what it means by "it gives instructions to the machine" - when you write JIL code you are giving the computer instructions, and the computer follows your instructions. It doesn't mean "a programming language is something that is translated into machine code", it means "I tell the computer what to do and it does it".

Comment: A programming language is any language that can "[be] used to write computer programs, which involve a computer performing some kind of computation". The *implementation* of such a language may target bare metal, some form of byte code, or use an underlying language as a host / runtime (which itself relies on an implementation), etc. If the only JIL run-time is written in Java, then that is the *implementation* of such.

Comment: Ahh, so JIL would be a [JVM](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) language... `Some of these languages are interpreted by a Java program'

Comment: And thanks a lot for your answers! I can seem to gather that JIL is, or rather will be, because it does almost nothing yet, a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using wiki's definition as a rule of the thumb:

> A programming language is a formal constructed language designed to
>   communicate instructions to a machine

yours is formal because it can be parsed. if it also instructs machine what to do then congratulations - your first programming language :)